# Show that every subset of a metric space is a metric subspace?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(M, d)$ be a complete metric space, ($M$ is equipped with metric $d$) and let $N$ be a nonempty subset of $M$. Then, prove that $(N,d)$ can be regarded as a metric space.

This statement seems intuitive to me, but I do not know how to show it.

Extension:

Prove $N$ is a closed set in $(M,d)$ if $(N,d)$ be a complete metric space.

I tried the following:

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $(N,d)$ where $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $x \in M$. Sine $(M,d)$ is a complete metric space there exist a Cauchy sequence $(y_n)$ in $(M,d)$ which converges to $x \in M$. Now I need to use completeness of $(N,d)$ or existence of $(y_n)$ to show that $x$ is indeed in $N$, so $N$ is closed.

I do not know how to that?

Comment: Just check the metric axioms. It's pretty easy to show that $(M,d)\to(N,d)$.

Comment: You are right. I revised the question, $(N,d)$ is a complete metric space.

Comment: Regarding the extension, let $x$ be a limit point of $N$. Then there is a sequence $x_n$ of points in $N$ such that $d(x_n, x) \to 0$. It's easy to show that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since $N$ is complete, $x_n$ converges to a point $y$ in $N$. Since limits are unique in metric spaces, $y=x$, hence $x \in N$, hence $N$ contains its limit points and is therefore closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show that $(N,d)$ is a metric space, you need to show that the axioms of metric space are satisfied.

1) $d(x,y)\ge 0$ for all $x$,$y$ in $N$.

2) $d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y $  fro all $x$,$y$ in $N$

3) $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ for all $x$,$y$ in $ N$

4) $ d(x,y)\le d(x,z) + d(z,y) $ for all $x$,$y$,$z$ in $N$

Since elements of $N$ are also elements of M, these properties are inherited from $(M,d)$ so they are satisfied.

Comment: Could you take a look at the extension and help me?

Comment: @Saeed you need to show that every limit point of $N$ is in $N$. A limit point of $N$ is  the limit of  some  convergent sequence in $M$, so it is Cauchy in $M$ which makes it Cauchy in $N$ and completeness on $N$ makes the limit to belong to $N$.   You can fill in the details.